# Glympse private groups / view only

Tags: glympse

I have shared a Glympse group via web to allow everyone to see where our team is.
Would it be possible to show only the team members position and forbid other people to share their position in the group? (with an user filter or a password for share)

Answer (score 0):

See here 'Creating a Password Protected Group': https://glympse.zendesk.com/entries/67512780-Creating-a-Password-Protected-Group